# Semaphore not working without sem_getvalue?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, semaphore

I'm really confused as to why this is not working, and since most the examples regarding semaphores are multithreaded and not multiprocessed I'm kind of stumped. My code does not work unless I put this above the sem_wait.

```
while (1)
    {
        int x;
        sem_getvalue(sem1, &x);
        if (x>0) break;
        sleep(1);
    }
```

Essentially making a semaphore myself... It's like the sem_wait only checks the value one time and then just sits forever. I have two producers and one consumer. Here is how it is structured:

```
Producer 1:
  sem_waits for sem1 (initially set to 1)
  sem_posts to sem2
Producer 2:
  sem_waits for sem2 (initially set to 0)
  sem_posts to sem1
```

Without that snippet producer 2 never runs. And with that snippet in producer 2 but not 1, producer 1 runs, then 2, and then stop. Both need that snippet to do their every other thing..

I feel like my problem is here:

```
// sem open must be used to be used by multiple processes?
sem_t *sem1 = sem_open("producer", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
sem_t *sem2 = sem_open("producer2", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
sem_t *consumer_full = sem_open("cfull", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
sem_t *consumer_empty = sem_open("cempty", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

// sem_open remains in memory even after program exit.
// initialize to correct value to be sure

sem_init(sem1,0,1);
sem_init(sem2,0,0);
sem_init(consumer_full,0,0);
sem_init(consumer_empty,0,0);
```

The sem_init changes the semaphores so they could only be shared by storing in shared memory? But how can I initialize a sem_open semaphore without designing some arbitrary do while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sem_init` is for creating anonymous semaphores. Calling it on a named semaphore opened via `sem_open` invokes undefined behavior. This is possibly the source of your problems. You're clobbering the named process-shared semaphores you opened with new anonymous non-process-shared semaphores, which would be semantically wrong even if it didn't invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Why is there not a set value for semaphores, especially named ones that used sem_open?

Comment: You set the value when creating it. Setting the value at any other time is a race condition and not a useful operation.

Comment: But if the program crashed sem_open does not re-initialize the value, so then the program is out of order. I just made a function to get the sem value to the correct initial state before starting processes.

Comment: That's why you need `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` which will make the `sem_open` fail if the semaphore already exists, in which case you can `sem_unlink` it and make a new one. Alternatively, if you *really* want to "set the value" of an existing semaphore, you can call `sem_trywait` in a loop until it fails, then `sem_post` sufficiently many times to achieve the desired value. But this has fundamental race conditions if other processes may be using the semaphore at the time you want to "reset the value".